# Масштабирование изображения, размещенного на `QGraphicsScene`

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

У меня есть `QPixmap`, помещенный в `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, который в свою очередь помещен на `QGraphicsScene`, а сцена размещена на `QGrahicsView`. Вопрос в том, как изменять размер этого `QPixmap` при срабатывании `QResizeEvent` у `QGraphicsView`?

Answer (score 0):

Как и любой иной объект на сцене - создаете класс, наследуете его от `QGraphicsPixmapItem` или `QGraphicsItem` и переопределяете функции `paint` и `boundingRect`, которые вызываются автоматически при перемещении и изменении размера объекта.
В Qt есть пример - `weatheranchorlayout`, в нем все описано.
Только `resizeEvent` не у `QGraphicsView` нужно переопределить, а у виджета(`QGraphicsWidget`), в который будет помещено изображение. Иначе откуда появиться событию `QResizeEvent` для объекта на сцене, а не для всей сцены?